# Conversão de uma string de "array" para um array javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um dado que vem como parâmetro de uma função.

```html
[['local','precipitação'],['RJ',0.2],['SP',0.8],['MG','']]
```

Este dado deveria ser reconhecido como array mas o javascript reconhece como string. Existe alguma forma de converter para um array?

Comment: Bruno, esse exemplo que você deu é uma array de arrays. Onde está a string que você quer transformar em array? Se for essa, você quer que vire um array único ou continue sendo um array de arrays?

Comment: Se eu colocar esse exemplo direto em uma variável funciona. Mas, se ele vier do parâmetro na função ele entende que é uma string. Eu preciso que seja lido como array de arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para converter a string `"[['local','precipitação'],['RJ',0.2],['SP',0.8],['MG','']]"` em um Array você pode usar `eval()`.

```
var s = "[['local','precipitação'],['RJ',0.2],['SP',0.8],['MG','']]";
var a = eval(s);
```

Alguns vão dizer que usar `eval` é má prática, por causa do risco de injeção de código, dificuldade de depurar etc.

Um pouco melhor seria usar `JSON.parse()`. Entretanto parece que ele não aceita aspas simples. Nesse caso ficaria algo assim:

```
var s = '[["local","precipitação"],["RJ",0.2],["SP",0.8],["MG",""]]';
var a = JSON.parse(s);
```

De qualquer forma o melhor mesmo seria evitar usar string desnecessariamente, e passar o argumento diretamente como Array.